# Null field getting updated with String 'NULL'

Tags: null, informatica

In my project, I need to modify an existing workflow in Informatica.
One of the fields in SQ query is `NULL`. When running the SQ query in DB, I can see the `NULL` value getting populated. But when writing into the target table, the column in target table getting populated with string `'NULL'` .Could you please help?

Thanks,
Ammu

Comment: It would help lots if you included the query that you're using. Without it there's not much that can be said.

Comment: The query fetched correct values when i ran it directly in the DB. Only problem is using informatica while writing into the target table its changing NULL to string 'NULL'

Comment: Informatica is not changing anything that you didn't make it change. Somewhere along the way(the select, an expression ETC) you changed it.

Comment: When i write the field to a flat file ,  null is not coming as string.But writing into target table directly is causing this issue.Also no transformations are used.Its a direct mapping from source to traget

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using Netezza database? I remember facing something similar with Netezza after upgrading informatica version. The NULLS were treated as string 'NULLS'. The solution was to add a custom property at the IS level or OSProfile level. I don't remember the exact custom property but I am guessing it was syncNetezzaNullwithPCNull=yes.